# How to fix 'There is already data' error in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, jms

I wish to add after serialization, the delivery date

so I created an event listener, with method "onPostSerialize".

here is my listener :

```php
namespace App\ApiBundle\Serializer\Listener;

use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\Events;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\ObjectEvent;

class BrandListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            [
                'event' => Events::POST_SERIALIZE,
                'format' => 'json',
                'class' => 'App\ApiBundle\Entity\Brand',
                'method' => 'onPostSerialize',
            ]
        ];
    }

    public static function onPostSerialize(ObjectEvent $event)
    {
        $object = $event->getObject();

        $date = new \Datetime();
        $event->getVisitor()->addData('delivered_at', $date->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'));
    }
}
```

even when emptying the cache, I have an error that tells me that a data has the same name (except that no)...

Here the error Symfony:

> InvalidArgumentException There is already data for "delivered_at"

.

Answer (score 0):

In app/config/services.yml change **autoconfigure** value to **false**

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function onPostSerialize(ObjectEvent $event): void
 {
    $propertyName = 'deliveredAt';
    $value        =  (new \DateTime())->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
    $className    = Brand::class;

    /** @var JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor */
    $visitor  = $event->getVisitor();
    $metadata = new VirtualPropertyMetadata($className, $propertyName);
    
    // check if property is displayed
    if ($visitor->hasData($metadata->name)) {
        $visitor->visitProperty(
            new StaticPropertyMetadata($className, $metadata->name, $value),
            $value
        );
    }
}
```

But also you can use another way: add [Virtual Property](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#virtualproperty) in **Brand** entity

```
/**
 * @JMS\VirtualProperty({name: "delivered_at"})
 */
public function getDeliveredAt()
{
    return (new \DateTime())->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
}
```